# I have mixed content in my website but i can't find it

Tags: javascript, http, https

I have mixed content in "https://indexstore.cl/product/kit-dvr-full-hd-8-ch-con-3-camara-sin-disco/", but i can't find it.
the console panel indicate this url, but is another web:
"jquery.js:3 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://indexstore.cl/product/kit-dvr-full-hd-8-ch-con-3-camara-sin-disco/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.indexpro.cl/wp-content/themes/porto/images/AjaxLoader.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."

If someone can help me i will apreciate it so much.

Comment: Please review the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) where the answer is "No". Also, the error indicates exactly where the problem is; something is requesting that "AjaxLoader.gif" over HTTP, not HTTPS. Search your code base for a reference to that and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above the answer is clear that AjaxLoader.gif is not being loaded over HTTPs thus the mixed content warning.  The bigger question is what is generating the link or causing that image to be rendered over HTTP instead of HTTPs screen.  Given it seems you are using WP this could be generated by any of the plugins you have setup in your website.

The solution to finding which plugin is doing it may take a bit of time but it is to disable each plugin until the error goes away then you found the culprit.  However, please note before you start any diagnostics be sure you turn off any site caching and clear your browser cache as well because chasing an issue only larger to discover the only reason you see it was because you were looking at a cached version is very annoying.